# Custom taxonomies relationship

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have CPT Cars, and it has 3 taxonomies Brand, Model, Engine

For example

- Brand - BMW
- models - 1,3,5
- Engine - 2.0, 1.6

So I have car BMW 1 1.6 and BMW 3 2.0- this is just rough example. Each CPT has correct taxonomy selected.

If I open taxonomy term page brand, for example BMW it will show all cars. What I need to do is to first show all BMW models (1,3,5) and then for selected model all it's engines (1 1.6, 1 2.0)

I know how to query custom taxonomies, but I can't figure out how to query relationship between them.

Comment: So when you go to example.com/BMW you get all cars. Than examples.com/BMW/Model_1 and so on. When you created your taxonomy did you make it hierarchical? If you did you can easily achieve what you want by properly categorizing them.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make everything hierarchical in the 1 taxonomy, what David is asking for is technically called a taxonomy intersection and should be possible via the `tax_query` parameter, a nicer answer will add rewrite rules in too

Comment: Yeah, nice answer would be great since I am stuck on this for quite time :)